# How to flatten a promise.all response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a list of products and for each product im making an api call to get the products subscription.

```
   const subscriptions = await Promise.all(products.flatMap((p: any) => {
        const { username, password } = p.credentials;
        return GetSubscription(username, password);
    }));
    console.log(subscriptions);
```

**Actual**:

> [   [
>       {},
>       {},
>       {},   ] ]

now you can see i have a double nested array here and i don't need the outer array, how can i flatten this array, i assumed using flatMap here might help me but it did not.

**Expected**:

> [
>       {},
>       {},
>       {},   ]

Ofcourse i could simply do `subscriptions[0]` but im trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: `Array.prototype.flat()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: ah the simple .flat does not make my api call GetSubscription so it did not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the spread operator

```js
async function func() {
  return 'A';
}

(async() => {
  const [...ret] = await Promise.all([
    func(),
    func(),
    func(),
  ]);

  console.log(ret);
})();
```

Or

```js
async function func() {
  return 'A';
}

(async() => {
  const ret = await Promise.all([
    func(),
    func(),
    func(),
  ]);

  console.log(ret.reduce((tmp, x) => [...tmp, x], []));
})();
```

---

As you said in your comment, specifying ES2019 in your tsconfig, you can use `Array.flat` :

```js
async function func() {
  return 'A';
}

(async() => {
  const ret = await Promise.all([
    func(),
    func(),
    func(),
  ]);

  console.log(ret.flat());
})();
```

Comment: property 'flat' does not exist on type '[unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown]'.

 console.log("here", subscriptions.flat());

Comment: Ah when using typescript i had to add "ES2019" to lib config

Comment: There is no Array.flat in basic typescript configuration. I assumed It existed, my bad... So the soluce would be to use the spread operator. or change the configuration as you pointed

Answer (score 2):

This should help you.

```js
const input = [[{}, {}, {}], [{"hi": "bye"}]];


console.log(input.flat());
```

Comment: property 'flat' does not exist on type '[unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown]'.

 console.log("here", subscriptions.flat());

Answer (score 0):

`Array.flatMap()` is the same as `Array.map().flat()`. So `await Promise.all(Array.map().flat())` will be applied to the result of `flat`. When the map callback is asynchronous you need to resolve the result of `map` before calling `flat`. In that case you would need to use `(await Promise.all(Array.map())).flat()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).